# Two Docks are shown when Super key is pressed

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

My system shows two docks when I press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key.

[image: screenshot]

I am using Dash to Dock extension.

The problem is resolved and works fine for couple of hours when I change the dock settings to bottom and then revert back to left (side).
See the screenshot for resolved issue.

I am looking for permanent solution, kindly let me know if available. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This appears to be a bug with the `dash-to-dock` extension:

- [Bug #855](https://github.com/micheleg/dash-to-dock/issues/855)

Some workarounds include:

> Toggling the 'Show on all monitors' corrected this issue for me. I'm not sure why

Or

> It looks like dash-to-dock isn't properly replacing/removing/etc (or whatever you do to default) the default dock. I was able to
>
> ```
> cd /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
> sudo mv ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com.bak
> ```
>
> and then <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> 'r' to manually fix it.