# Double Side Docks Docks on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, ubuntu-dock, dock

Im running Ubuntu 20.04 today and I noticed that whenever I hit the super key or move apps towards the dock to autohide, that there are two docks, one behind the other.

I made sure to check in the Extensions app that Dask to Dock was disabled and it was. How can I make sure that I have only one dock running ?

[image: Dock Double]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Two Docks are shown when Super key is pressed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1105668/two-docks-are-shown-when-super-key-is-pressed)